# SKEmitterNode leaves particles on the screen after being removed from the parent

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

In my game, I have added a particle effect using SKEmitterNode that plays for a few seconds then is removed from the game.

However, when removed, the particles are left on the screen permanently.

This is the code to add and also remove the emitter:

```
    // debrisNode is a child of scene
    let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "shatter.sks"),
    emitter.name = debrisNode.name
    emitter.targetNode = scene

    debrisNode.addChild(emitter)

    debrisNode.run(
        .sequence([
            .scale(to: 0.1, duration: 1),
            .run {
                emitter.particleBirthRate = 0
                emitter.targetNode = nil
                emitter.removeAllChildren()
                emitter.removeFromParent()
            }]))
```

Edit: I now think that this is related to my use of `targetNode`. When I set `targetNode = debrisNode`, the particles go away - but I need targetNode to make any animation look right.

Comment: Do the particles only live for as long as their lifespan?

Comment: Yes they do, but when the animation ends, whatever particles that were still on the screen get left behind.

Comment: did you try only emitter.removeFromParent() and make sure it's called?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia Yes, with the same result.

Comment: do the particles left behind live forever, or do they slowly die out in accordance with their lifespan?

Comment: @Confused The particles that are left behind do not slowly die out. They live forever stuck in place.

Comment: only one option then, let the particle system live until all the particles are dead, then remove it.